# Как передать this от текущего элемента jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Есть событие клика по элементу a:

```
$('.edit_comment li a').click(function(){

 function MyFunct();
}
```

Как передать внутрь функции `this` от события, чтобы в `MyFunct` я могу обращаться так
`$(this).closest('div'); //` Найти ближайщий div от ссылки, по которой кликнули

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$('.edit_comment li a').click(function() {
    var element = this;
SaveChangesEditComments(element, null)
});

function SaveChangesEditComments(element, changedText) { 
    var data = element.attr('data');  // не получаю нужное
});
```

Comment: что за аттрибут data ?

Comment: А спустя 3 года можно спросить, спросил ли он тогда ответ?

Answer (score 7):

Обычно вот так:

```
$('.edit_comment li a').click(MyFunct);

function MyFunct();
{
    console.log($(this))
}
```

но если this меняется, скажем при setTimeout то так:

```
$('.edit_comment li a').click(function() {
var that=this;
setTimeout(function() 
    console.log("timeout started");
    MyFunct.apply(that,{a:1,b:4}); //передать функции that как её this (сменить контекст)

},100);

function MyFunct(args);
{
    console.log($(this),args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Плохо знаком с JQuery, но могу подсказать предполагаемый алгоритм. Найти сначала общий с

```
$('.edit_comment li a')
```

родительский элемент и потом с ним работать.
И по-моему JQuery не поддерживает "самодельные" внутри себя функции.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
var data = $(element).attr('data');
```

вместо

```
var data = element.attr('data');
```

Comment: вы бы сами попробовали.

Comment: А что вам не нравится в этом способе?

Человек в теле функции пытался получить доступ к методу, которого у объекта 'element' нет, т.к. это не объект jQuery - я ему подсказал как это исправить.

Comment: сорри две строчки перепутал местами :)

Answer (score 0):

Разве так нельзя? Я Вас правильно понял?

```js
function myfunction(element){
    console.log(element);
    element.animate({.......or other 
}
$("#some_block a" ).click(myfunction($(this)));
```

Comment: спустя два года после того, как вопрос задан, спрашивать у автора, правильно ли вы его поняли, скорее всего, бессмысленно.